# Simple JS function using text inputs and parseInt, returns NaN

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me figure out why I keep getting a NaN result?

```
   function showShares() {
 var tot = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML;
 var pri = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
 var per = document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML;

 var shar = parseInt(tot, 10) * parseFloat(per) / parseFloat(pri);
   document.getElementById("shares").innerHTML=Math.round(shar);

}
```

---

```
<td><text id="price"><%= StockQuote::Stock.quote(current_user.fund1).last %></text></td>

 <td><text id="shares"></text></td>
 <td><text id="percent">.50</text></td>
```

---

```
<p class="alignright1"><input type="text" id="total" size="8"></input>
<br><a href onclick="showShares()">here</a>
```

---

The stock quote is returning an integer in the cell ie. 25.38.  it returns the same NaN if I remove the embedded ruby and place a simple integer ie. 50.  The same is true if I replace the input with a number.

Thank You

Comment: Debug, e.g. `alert( parseInt(tot, 10) + ' | '+ parseInt(per, 10) +' | '+parseInt(pri, 10) )`

Comment: NaN | NaN | 23 .. Thats Cool!

Comment: `document.getElementById('total').innerHTML` isn't the way to get a value from an input element. Try `document.getElementById('total').value`

Comment: Thank You Very Much! I was using .value earlier.  The debug code was very Helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
function showShares() {
 var tot = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML;
 var pri = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
 var per = document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML;

 var shar = parseInt(tot, 10) * parseFloat(per, 10) / parseInt(pri, 10);
   document.getElementById("shares").innerHTML=Math.round(shar);

}
```

The percent value is a float (digit with comma) and must be interpreted by the JS engine like a float ;)

Comment: Thank You, I had just realized this too.  Combined with the debug help above I get NaN | .5 | 23

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a value from an input element with this code, 
`document.getElementById('total').innerHTML`

That's not the way to get the value from the input. You should use this code,

`document.getElementById('total').value`